# What is purpose of MIDI in java if it is not used to play the song

Tags: java, user-interface, midi, javasound, synthesizer

I was learning javasound for music player but I am confused about MIDI and synthesizer in java what is the difference b/w them ?

Comment: See the [Java Sound info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) for **Playing a MIDI Sequence** to see how to play a MIDI using Java Sound.  It is quite easy.

Answer (score 1):

MIDI is a control protocol usually used for controlling synthesizers.  It was originally devised for different musical hardware to be able to communicated with each other.  That is, I can have a control keyboard and a rack of synthesizers from different manufacturers, and I can control that whole rack with my control keyboard.  MIDI messages are not sound themselves.  A typical MIDI message turns a note on or a note off.  It also supports transferring patch data and what not.

The synthesizer is what actually takes all of these commands and produces sound.  All the note on/off, control change, patch change, etc.